# Comparable<T> and compareTo

Tags: java, interface, comparable

I don't understand how interfaces like Comparable works exactly, does it include a written compareTo-method that I can use? Or do I have to @override and create one myself?

Comment: If you're even expecting that Comparable to have an implementation of compareTo, you got to go back and read about interfaces - they cannot have any concrete method (At least till Java 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Compareable<T>` contains a `compareTo` method with the type parameter `T`.
See the documentation: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

You also get the explicit type parameter from the object, so you don't need any cast. Some datatypes already have implemented `compareTo` e.g.

```
Integer x = 5;
int compareValue = x.compareTo(3);

String str = "Hallo";
compareValue = str.compareTo("Hallo");
```

Comment: How do I implement it's method into my code? Or do I write the method myself?

Comment: You have to implement it but the interface gives you the method structure.

Comment: Alright, so it only gives me the method signature, but not the actual method itself?

Comment: Exactly some datatypes already implemented the interface so you can use it.